# how to use Keras Conv2D dilation_rate parameter without subsampling?

Tags: keras, cntk

When I pass in the `dilation_rate` parameter to `Conv2D`, the resulting output is sub-sampled.  E.g.,

```
inputs = Input(shape=(160,240,1))
lay = Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3,3), dilation_rate=(2,2), use_bias=False)(inputs)
print(lay)
```

yields

```
Composite(input_1: Tensor[160,240,1]) -> Tensor[78,118,32]
```

As you can see from the output, the 160x240 input is being subsampled to 78x118.  This seems wrong to me.  Using a dilated convolution should not necessarily imply that I want a subsampled result.  Is there some sort of workaround for this?

I'm running `Keras 2.0.6` with `CNTK 2.2` backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is certainly related to the cntk backend. I cannot reproduce it using the tensorflow or theano backends. (I get a shape of (?, 156, 236, 32))

I suggest explicitly setting the strides option to 1 (it should be the default, even if it is not for the cntk backend).